# Magento 2 - how to set final price for product on view page

Tags: magento2, price, product-view

Magento frontend product view page i need to set custom final price,

how to set?  I tried **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php** in this file **getFinalprice** function but not  working with plugin

can anyone  give suggestion

Comment: what you want when customer trying to add product to cart then during this a custom price should be set?

Comment: no, when i open product need to display my custom price i am calculating price with some extra amount if min sale qty is less than 5 i need to display my custom price like price * my extra fee

Answer (score 0):

The class you're looking for is Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice

The below code will double the final price as an example:

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice">
        <plugin name="vendorname_modulename_catalog_pricing_price_finalprice" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\FinalPrice" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin/FinalPrice.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class FinalPrice
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $subject
     * @param float $result
     * @return float
     */
    public function afterGetValue(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $subject, $result)
    {
        return $result * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: here the problem is i am unable to get product data

Comment: You can do $subject->getProduct() to get the product data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use event observer for the price change on the product page.
You may use following event

```
catalog_controller_product_view
```

and in the observer you may use following code.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $customPrice = 4;
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $product->setFinalPrice($customPrice);
}
```